# How to get minified bundles in angular 4?

Tags: angular

**How to get minifide bundle file**

When I build in angular I get unminified files, if I want to get minified file what I have to do?

```
chunk {0} polyfills.95b046c48c8687ee05b2.bundle.js (polyfills) 64.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.28b9d0734db4fef006f8.bundle.js (main) 3.44 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css (styles) 0 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} vendor.cf010a7df6bd1105978d.bundle.js (vendor) 1.59 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} inline.31e1fb380eb7cf3d75b1.bundle.js (inline) 798 bytes [entry] [rendered]
```

Build command used

```
ng build -prod
```

Comment: Why would you think they are not minimized? Just because they do not have a `min.js` suffix does not mean there is no minification.

Comment: File size looks big....i want the small bundle size...as it taking more time to load.

Comment: `Looks big` is hardly proof that there is no minification. Open up the generated file(s) in a text editor, you should see that the files are minified.

Comment: There have also been improvements in tree shaking over the past couple of versions. You should see the file size(s) decrease if you upgrade your angular version to the latest (currently 6) as well as some increased performance.

Comment: Thank you files are minified....how I can reduce the bundle size?

Comment: See my last comment. Also https://update.angular.io/

Comment: Take a look at `source-map-explorer` and read over Angulars deployment suggestions https://angular.io/guide/deployment. Also consider upgrading to Angular v6 - there have been many improvements when it comes to build optimization compared to v4.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is please open the generated bundles and then see if they are minified. You can't conclude that they are not minified as they don't have min in their name.
Few things that can help with the bundle size optimization.

1. Optimise rxjs size in your bundle, if you are including the entire library by mistake. This is always a good practise and it will reduce the rxjs dependency.

   [rxjs imports in an optimised manner](https://medium.com/@rishantagarwal/how-to-import-modules-from-rxjs-in-an-optimized-manner-69566f68f13f)
   Example : `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx'` will import the entire rxjs module even if you just want the Observable class
   Optimised way is to import just the class : `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'`.
   Note above example is based on rxjs version less than 6.0.0.
2. In Production you will have the GZipped files for which the size is very less when compared to just the minified versions.
3. Check out [angular aot build](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler), [Angular CLI build options](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build).
4. Use [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) or [source-map-explorer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer) to analyse the generated bundles.

These articles can help you in exploring further

- [angular-performance-checklist](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-performance-checklist)
- [optimising-performance-of-your-enterprise-angular-application](https://ordina-jworks.github.io/angular/2017/04/04/optimising-performance-of-your-enterprise-angular-application.html)

Comment: For point 3, the build flag `-prod` enables `aot` by default. For point 2, what do you mean the GZipped files? For point 1, you should include a reference link because that statement itself is not clear if you do not already have experience doing this.

Comment: @igor can yu check the answer now, i did include the references for everything and i did personally optimise rxjs which reduced its size in the bundle, i have seen 30% improvement after optimising. Also prod build doesnt generate vendor bundle but rather generated a common.hash.bundle.js unless we give a flag `--vendor-bundle=true`, but i see vendor bundle in the SS attached in question.

Comment: @Igor Also for point 2 GZip is a format of compressing files, when we host the app in a web server or cloud we will serve the GZipped files which have less size when compared to minified files. If you have tried out webpack bundle analyser it does show the size of each bundle in 3 types - stat, parsed and Gzip from which you can figure out the difference.